# Data object in JSON not showing as expected

Tags: java, mysql, sql, json, spring

I have two Tables in a Database. One is Orders other one is Product.

This is a class *Order*

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orders", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Product> products;
```

This is a class *Product*

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "orders_products",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private Set<Order> orders;
```

When I send a request to REST API to add a *Product* into an *Order*:

> localhost:8080/order/1/add/products?ids=1

I'll get a result as expected:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Order number one description",
    "name": "Shopping cart for mobiles",
    "surcharge": 20.0,
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "Samsung S9",
            "price": 599.99
        }
    ]
}
```

]

After all when I send a GET request to get all orders:

> localhost:8080/order

I will get this result:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Order number one description",
    "name": "Shopping cart for mobiles",
    "surcharge": 20.0,
    "products": []
}
```

]

**I want "products" to be open to see actual products in. Why are "products" empty or is it not showing body of "products".**

Thank you.

UPDATE:

It does not persist in database, under table *orders_products*. Check in *Product* class in *@JoinTable( name = ...)*.

If I do following:

> select * from products;

```
# product_id    description price
1   Samsung S9  599.99
2   Notebook S9 1000.99
3   Headset 1000.99
4   Mone    45.99
```

> select * from orders;

```
# order_id  description name    surcharge   user_id
1   Order number one description    Shopping cart for mobiles   20  2
2   Order for notebooks test second 20  2
```

But If I do.
There should be ID's from order_id poiting to some of product_id.
As @k-wasilewski was data does not persist in database.

> select * from orders_products;

```
# product_id, order_id
   null        null
```

On demand of @Turing85 I am adding some code from OrderService class.

```
    public List<Order> mapProductsToOrderById(final Long id, List<Long> ids) {
    Order order = orderRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
            () -> new OrderNotFoundException("Order with id: " + id + " was not found."));

    List<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
    Set<Product> resultSet = order.getProducts();
    
    ids.forEach(x -> products.forEach(product -> {
        if(product.getId().compareTo(x) == 0){
            resultSet.add(productRepository.findById(x).orElseThrow(
                    () -> new ProductNotFoundException("Product with id: " + x + " was not found.")
            ));
            order.setProducts(resultSet);
            orderRepository.save(order);
        }
    }));
    return orderRepository.findAll();
}
```

There is method from Controller class.

```
    @GetMapping("{id}/add/products")
    public List<Order> mapProductsToOrder(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam("ids") List<Long> ids) {
    return orderService.mapProductsToOrderById(id, ids);
}
```

Comment: Please create a [MRE]. Without seeing the relevant code, we cannot fully analyze the problem.

Comment: Does adding a product actually persist it in a correct way to the db?

Comment: did you try fetchtype eager instead of lazy ?

Comment: @Turing85 I have updated post. Please have a look and let me know if you need more code.

Comment: @k-wasilewski Yes you are right data's does not persist in database. I think problem is in Order and Product classes, where I am trying to Join them. I updated post please have a look.

Comment: @coderaty Yes. I have tryed Eeager. Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move method mapProductsToOrderById to ProductService.class.
And do same as you did by adding products into order by in reverse. So you add orders into products set.

Comment: Thanks. I through that problem is in JoinColums